# Arabic number not shown properly

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i am using FOP 2.4 to obtain a PDF document from a combination of XML and XSLT. everything is fine except number that need to be shown in farsi(arabic or hindi in MS Office) font. i am using this code to get number value of a block and format that:
`<xsl:number value="rahgiri" format="&#x0623;" lang="fa"/>`
the result is: [image]

but needed result is: [image]

any help is appreciated

Comment: I am not familiar with the numbering system but with FOP to get a system font to be used that is installed on the system where you run FOP you might need to configure it and you might need to play with `font-family` e.g. `<fo:block font-family="Arial"><xsl:number value="265144" format="&#x661;" lang="fa"/></fo:block>` does show something very different to `265144` although to me `٢٦٥١٤٤` looks completely different to the one you have shown.

Comment: @Martin i tried multiple fonts but those didn't work for me. did you define Arial font in your configuration? because i tried both non configured and configured Arial neither gave me the right appearance of the numbers

Comment: I think using `<auto-detect/>` in the configuration described in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/site/deploy/fop/trunk/fonts.html#autodetect can help FOP find and use more than the default PDF fonts and look at and use system/os installed fonts. That is what I is usually try to set up.

Comment: What is in the XSL-FO file that is the result of the XSLT transformation? It looks like your XSLT processor does not understand the `format` and/or doesn't do anything for `lang="fa"`. If the XSLT processor is not generating the right digits, then it's not surprising if you're getting the wrong formatted output.